# Java - how to set Local Storage values in a HTTP GET request?

Tags: java, local-storage, session-cookies, http-get

I am trying to do an HTTP GET request to a website that needs authentication and it normally stores the auth token in browsers' Local Storage.

[image: Firefox Local Storage]

I tried to set this token using `CookieHandler` and `CookieStore`, but the website only search this token in browsers' Local Storage.

How can I simulate this Local Storage in a Command Line Java Program?

Comment: Do you need a rest test?

Comment: local storage is used by the code on a webpage. It is not used automatically when building a request / receive response. If you want to simulate a call to a protected endpoint, you will have to simulate / execute an authentication then use the access token to include it on the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) and logging in on starting.